# save changes of fragment when fragment is replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

i have implemented Drawer menu in my application. i have 7 different fragments in my app. the MainActivity which holds all the fragments is drawer activity. i have overriden the **`onBackPressed()`** method in this activity. i have a fragment where i would like user to save the data he has changed. that is if user have changed something in one fragment and without saving it if user leaves fragment (By selecting another fragment from drawer menu or by pressing a back button) then i want to show the confirmation dialog to user on same fragment where the changes were made. as an example.. if user have made some change in sixth fragment and he leaves the fragment (by selecting any other fragment or back button) i want to show user a confirmation dialog on sixth fragment itself. from where according to his input he can move the selected fragment or stay in the fragment where he made some changes.

Here is the snap of a code of my DrawerActivity.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB=0;
            return;
        }
        else { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

        mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 0;
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.home);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_progress:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 1;
            fragment = new ProgressFragment();
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.progress);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_workouts:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 2;
          /*  if (Utilities.getInstance().getPreferences(DrawerActivity.this, AppConstants.PREF_KEY_USER_INFO,
                    AppConstants.PREF_KEY_SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, "").equals("1")){
                fragment = new FragmentPremiumClasses();
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.premium);
            }else {*/
                fragment = new WorkoutsFragment();
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.workouts);
          //  }
            break;
        case R.id.nav_subscription:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 3;
            if (!Utilities.getInstance().getPreferences(DrawerActivity.this, AppConstants.PREF_KEY_USER_INFO,
                    AppConstants.PREF_KEY_SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, "").equals("1")){
                fragment = new SubscriptionFragment();
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.subscription);
            } else {
                fragment = new SelectSocietyFragment();
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.newsubscription);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.nav_aboutUs:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 4;
            fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.aboutus);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 5;
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.settings);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            isLogoutClicked = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREF_KEY_USER_INFO,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            AppConstants.SELECTED_NAVIGATION_TAB = 0;
            Utilities.getInstance().finishAndStartIntent(DrawerActivity.this, MainActivity.class, 0, 0);
            break;
    }

    if (!isLogoutClicked) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope i have made the question clear, how to achieve this functionality? any help would be much appreciated :)

thanks :)

Comment: if you want data to store/show only till application is active then You can create Global class and store value in variable there,but if you want to store even if Application is not active, then use SharedPreference to store/retrieve data..

Comment: i want to call a webservice and store data, the problem is i am not able to figure out how i am going to do that. if i write onDestroyView() for fragment then its showing dialog on the next fragment

Comment: post your MainActivity class code here

Comment: here if  i change something in settings fragment and then select some other fragment then i want to show alert before replacing fragment

Answer (score 0):

Save data in **onPause()** of fragment.

Comment: Take flag in application class .Suppose user is writing something on edittext than make that flag true .On drawer fragment check that variable if flag is true than show alert .